# What is $2^\Omega$ with $\Omega=\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In the context of probability measures and "product measure":

What is $2^\Omega$ (the power set) when $\Omega=\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$?

I found a [reference](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matsr/ProbI/Lecture2.pdf) referring to "Product $\sigma$-algebra". Is $2^\Omega$ it? The same reference has the definition of "product measure", but is referring to some "produce $\sigma$-algebra F", rather than $2^\Omega$ which I've been given in my task (it's basically asking the proof of product measure being a probability measure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^{\Omega}$ is the set of all subsets of $\Omega$.

So, if $\Omega = \Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2} = \{(x,y) \mid x \in \Omega_{1}, y \in \Omega_{2} \}$, then the set of all possible subsets of this is denoted $2^{\Omega}$.

Now, the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all subsets of $\Omega$ of the form $A \times B$, where $A \subseteq \Omega_{1}$ and $B \subseteq \Omega_{2}$ and $A$ is measurable in $\Omega_{1}$ and $B$ is measurable in $\Omega_{2}$.

So $\mathcal{F}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all sets of the form $A \times B$ with $A$ and $B$ measurable (here, $A \times B$ is called a measurable rectangle).

Note that $\mathcal{F}$ is not necessarily equal to $2^{\Omega}$ but is definitely a subset of $2^{\Omega}$ (why are they not necessarily equal?).